# How long will a vinegar based marinade keep in fridge?

Tags: marinade

How long does a vinegar based marinade stay safe to use if keept in the refrigerator?

Comment: Presumably you mean after it's been prepared, but before it's actually been used as a marinade, correct? Also: it would be best to list the full ingredients in case it contains anything else of particular concern.

Comment: As explained in the other question: anything you prepare has a fridge shelf life of 3-5 days. There are exceptions, but they were designed by experts. If you are not following a special recipe for preserved food, you are supposed to throw it out on day 5.